# jinja2 iterate through list of tuples

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of tuples called *items*:

```
[ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) ]
```

I thought I could iterate though using, but it's not working:

```
# Code
output = template.render( items )

# Template
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item[0] }};
    {{ item[1] }};
{% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template.render):

> render([context])
>
> This method accepts the same arguments as the dict
> constructor: A dict, a dict subclass or some keyword arguments. If no
> arguments are given the context will be empty.

```
from jinja2 import Environment

TEMPLATE = """ 
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item[0] }};
    {{ item[1] }};
{% endfor %}
"""

template = Environment().from_string(TEMPLATE)

items = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]

print(template.render(items=items))
```

While parsing the template, jinja2 will look for a key called 'items' but in your case, there is none, you have to explicitly specify it.

Comment: for python 3, needs parens in the last line. `print (template.render(items=items))`